# Property 'load' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement

Tags: angular, typescript

Getting an warning on my typescript file:

***Property 'load' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'.***

.ts file:

`document.getElementById('audio-player').load();`

html:

`<audio preload="auto" controls #audio id="audio-player">
         <source src={{music}}>

        </audio>`

I've already tried this, but I'm getting the same error.

```
let load: HTMLElement = document.getElementById('audio-player').load();
```